# Sum of text source delimited by whitespace

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, text

How to get the sum of each column from file like:

```
123  32  122
43   11  0
444  112 32
```

and give the result as:

```
610 155 154
```

in a simple command?

It should be easy in Perl, but I'd like to know if someone had already packaged it in universe repository or somewhere else, along with other utilities to do with text tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`cat foo | awk '{ SUM += $1; SUM1 += $2; SUM3 += $3} END { print SUM, SUM1, SUM3 }'`

Comment: The column count is undetermined.

Answer (score 1):

awk is nice for these types of tasks

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) sum[i]+=$i} END {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%3d ", sum[i]; printf "\n"}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: \
  map(lambda pair: pair[0] + pair[1], zip(x, y)), \
  [map(int, n.split()) for n in file("foo", "r").read().splitlines()])
```

where the number of columns and integer size is limited by available memory.